# SFML SocketSelector::wait() некорректно работает

Tags: c++, tcp, sfml

Делаю небольшой мессенджер (протокол TCP). Есть сервер и клиент.
Уже почти все написал, но решил принятие пакетов на клиенте убрать в отдельный поток и запихивать все пакеты в очередь.

Вот его небольшой кусок:

```
client->getSocketSelector()->add(*client->getSocket());

while (client->isRun()) {
    m_conditionHandling.wait(handler_lock, [this]() { return m_isRun; });
    if (client->getSocketSelector()->wait(sf::seconds(1))) {
        if (client->getSocketSelector()->isReady(*client->getSocket())) {
            sf::Packet packet;
            m_status = client->getSocket()->receive(packet);
            if (m_status == sf::Socket::Done) {
                queue.push(packet);
                //...
            }
         }
     }
}
```

(`m_conditionHandling` нужен, чтобы запускать этот поток только после подключения к серверу `socket.connect()` и тормозить, если отсоединился от сервера)

Сначала я отправляю серверу запрос на выдачу информации о нем

```
getSocket()->send(packet);
```

И рассчитываю на то, что мне придет ответ от сервера. На сервере видно, что от клиента пришел пакет, сервер создает пакет с данными о нем и его благополучно отправляет и выдает `sf::Status::Done`,
но вот функция

```
client->getSocketSelector()->wait(sf::seconds(1))
```

никак не реагирует и остается `false`, мало того, она не ждет 1 секунду. Так еще если я убираю этот `timeout`, то функция так же не блокирует выполнения, а благополучно выходит из if(), хотя в документации написано, что по умолчанию `timeout = sf::Time::Zero` и эта функция будет ждать бесконечно пакет.

В чем может быть проблема? Что я не так делаю?

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение. добавил в `SocketSelector` сокет клиента уже после подключения к серверу и заработало.